# There was an error activating the remote language server, C# language

Tags: c#, visual-studio

After downloading devExpress extension, I got this error. But I don't know how to fix it. Please help me, thank you so much.
[My problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRSA4.png)

[My .xml file is on mediafire.](http://www.mediafire.com/file/7uwk6zk97p3wj77/ActivityLog.xml/file)

Comment: Please write down the content of the error in the question.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem through the information you gave me, so please provide the code you wrote and the platform you used so that I can help you solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error. It disappeared after I logged in to VS, then restarted the program.

Answer (score 1):

The one and only solution that worked for me is to update the visual studio to the latest version and boom!

Comment: I have downloaded the latest version 16.08 but no luck , still error poping up.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this error in the comupter of one of our collaborators. I've just sent these files from my computer to him. So he's replaced the files in his machine and the problem was solved. I think this way we've avoided to spend hours to update Visual Studio.

Comment: what files did you sent to him?

Comment: Sorry @active92, I don't remember the name of the files, but I remember that when I got the error, there was a message indicating what files.